# Phalcon and url not found

Tags: php, httpd.conf, phalcon

I downloaded invo-master, and the main page is loaded but links doesn't work and i don't know why.. I added this line to httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName phalcon
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/invo-master/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/inv-master/public>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My config.ini

```
 [application]
controllersDir = ../app/controllers/
modelsDir      = ../app/models/
viewsDir       = /../app/views/
pluginsDir     = ../app/plugins/
libraryDir     = ../app/library/
baseUri        = /
```

My loader in index.php

```
 $loader->registerDirs(
        array(
            $config->application->controllersDir,
            $config->application->pluginsDir,
            $config->application->libraryDir,
            $config->application->modelsDir,
        )
    )->register();
```

.htaccess

```
 AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Maybe a "o" is missing from  <Directory /var/www/html/inv-master/public> ?

Comment: what a shame :D thank you so much and sorry for my weak eyes, I spent over 3 hours on this, and I did not see this :D thanks for you eagle eyes :D